# Is facebook sdk(iOS) supporting ipv6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, sdk

Our App was refused, and the problem was IPV6. this screenshot is feedback from Apple.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4LCv.png). If I login in IPV6，it was always showing the indicator, but if not in IPV6, it would work.

If someone knows that,pls help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same issue. Mine was also rejected due to IPV6. Check below two things for your application:

Facebook SDK is 100% support IPv6. So just check below steps to resolve your issue.

1) Make sure you API link which you used in your application, doesn't have any IP address. If you calling API using IPAddress then your application will be rejected.

2) Do testing your application using IPV6 network through your system. Here is the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html).

If your application is fulfilled both test case, then don't do anything, just write comment in iTuneConnect and told them that my application is running in IPV6 network. Can you please guide to find my issue? If possible then can I have a call with your representative?

So they ask your contact detail and give you call and your issue will be resolved. I have wasted around 20 days to solved this issue. But Apple representative told that this is them internal issue.

So my humble advice to contact Apple representative as soon as possible and your issue will resolve without doing anything.

Comment: Thx a lot. I'll make sure my API and test my application.

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides the standard error message about IPv6 when the app is not able to respond within the given threshold time for any HTTP network request. In your case most probable cause of app getting rejected is that at some point in your app during the review process the app has not received the response from server due to which the spinner has continued spinning.

Also make sure you don't use any hard coded IP addresses in your network requests and must use fully qualified domain names for accessing RESTFul APIs.